# how to fix Scala error with "Not found type"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm newbie in Scala, just trying to learn it in Spark. Now I'm writing a Scala app to load csv file from hadoop into dataframe, then I want to add a new column in that dataframe. There is a function to populate the content of that new column, for testing the function just uppercase the column from csv file, the csv file only contains one column: emp_id and it's string.. the function is defined in Object TestService. My IDE is Eclipse. Now I have error: not found: type TestService

Very appreciate if anyone can help me.

```
\\This is the main:
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


import com.poc.spark.service.TestService;


object SparkIntTest {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    sys.props.+=(("hadoop.home.dir","C:\\OpenSource\\Hadoop"))

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("employee").set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("employee").getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(".\\src\\main\\resources\\employee.csv")

    df.show();

    println(df.schema);

    val df_Applied = df.withColumn("award_rule",runAllRulesUDF(df("emp_id")))
    df_Applied.show();
    println(df_Applied.schema)

  }
  def runAllRulesUDF = udf(new TestService().runAllRulesForUDF(_:String))

}
```

Here is the Object TestService:

```
package com.poc.spark.service

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object TestService {

  def runAllRulesForUDF(empid: String): String = {

    empid.toUpperCase();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestService` is an `object`, which means that it is a statically created singleton.  So instead of

```
new TestService()
```

You can just say

```
TestService
```